# How to clear the call log in Android?

Tags: android

I would like to clear ALL the call history in my Android phone programmatically and I have tried developed a simple apps for doing so. But it is not working and I hope someone can just help me to check it.

```
public class ClearLogActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
Button clear;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    clear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    clear.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View view){

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        getContentResolver().delete(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls");

int d  = getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
```

or check how many deleted

```
int res = Call_logs.this.getContentResolver().delete(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,"_ID = "+ calls_id_list.get(i),null);
        if (res == 1) {
            // Log delete

        } else {
            // Log not Delete

        }
```

Comment: It is probably safer to use the static URI string (as you've done in the second example) than to hard code the URI string like you did in the first example. `android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI`

Comment: I have tried this
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls");
    getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
but it is still not working

Comment: Did you add there permission ? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />